# Storybook inconsistent styling

Tags: reactjs, next.js, styled-components, storybook

I'm setting up my components in storybook and I'm having an inconsistent behavior between what appears on the web and what appears in the tool. I've spent a good while now tweaking and changing the styles yet nothing is working. Any thoughts would be causing this?

**Styles**

```
const WidgetWrapper = styled.div<{
  warning?: boolean;
  complete?: boolean;
}>`
  cursor: default;
  border: 1px solid ${colors.grey[800]};
  ${({ warning }) => warning && `border: 1px solid ${colors.red[200]}`};
  ${({ complete }) => complete && `border: 1px solid ${colors.grey[800]}`};
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: ${theme.layout.boxShadow.sharp};
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
`;

const InnerContent = styled.div<{ warning?: boolean; complete?: boolean }>`
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  border: 4px solid ${colors.offWhite};
  ${({ warning }) => warning && `border: 4px solid ${colors.red[400]}`};
  ${({ complete }) => complete && `border: 4px solid ${colors.lightShades}`};
  background-color: ${colors.offWhite};
`;
```

---

**On my webpage:**

[image]

---

**within storybook:**

[image]

Comment: Can you share with us a copy of the styles applied to both the components in storybook, as well as the other context? You can copy it from the elements tab in your chrome dev tools. My intuition is there's some additional global styles making the styles work in your app, but not in storybook.

Comment: I'm seeing similar behaviour when using borders. Have you raised a Github issue?

Comment: @Calibre i have not, no.